# Conditional formatting with multiple conditions (lost between IF or AND, and not empty cells !)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google

I am trying to combine formulas here, to put color on specific cells (out of a specific range) when they are not empty, **and** when a checkbox in another cell is checked.

Here is what I tried :

```
=AND($D4=TRUE,$F04:AU<>””)
```

D4 is where the checkbox is, and if it is checked, the color must apply on the cells from F4 to AU only is they are not empty! As you can see on the picture below, D column is ticked so the whole range is colored, but I need only where is is written "2" in that line.

[image]

Can someone help me?

I tried the IF formula also, but could not get through. Same with AND and using TRUE, or ISBLANK for F4:AU.

Comment: You select range to which Conditional formatting will be applied in "Apply to range" section. No need to dub it in formula, try  =AND($D$4=TRUE,F4<>””)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to address my question ! I tried it, although nothing came out of it. I put the whole range in the formula, as each cell from F to AU that is not empty, when the D cell of that line is ticked (checkbox), I need to apply the color format to it.

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot and more explanations. Thank you !! ^^

Comment: ok i see, since you have tickbox for each row there is no need for absolute ref $D$4 from my previous comment. Try =AND($D4=TRUE,F4<>””)

Comment: Formula is staying red, and will not apply. I also tried =AND($D4=TRUE,$F4:AU<>"") to make sure it applied to the whole range if cell is not empty, but still nothing.

Comment: Would be better if you shared sample sheet.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: The document contains several dozens of tabs, each of them is confidential. I tried to copy and paste in another spreadsheet, just to get an extract, and it did not keep the formulas. I tried also this : =AND($D4=TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK($F4:AU))) which did not work, same for COUNTBLANK. Actually, all formulas always stay red, am I forgetting a thing in them ?